# java split strings inside quotes

Tags: java, regex, string, split

Is there a way using Java `String.split(regexp)` to split on strings inside of quotes, and not get the quotes?
The strings I have to deal with are like the following. I don't have control of the format and the number of strings are variable:

```
"strA" : "strB" : "strC" : "strD",
"strE" : "strF" : "strG",
```

Note: The spaces are included, and each line is handled separately.
So what I would like to get is an array with all strings.

I could use `replaceAll` to strip the quotes, spaces and commas, then split on the colon:

```
line = line.replaceAll(/(\"|,\\s+)/,"");
usrArray = line.split(":");
```

But I'd like to do this with one regexp.

Comment: Looks like a JSON. You might consider just parsing the JSON string.

Comment: show us more of what you are parsing. it seems like the data you are trying to parse is JSON and there exist parsers for that type of format already

Comment: This is not a JSON, it's actually a series of strings in quotes separated by colons, I just included two with user/role names for simplicity.  I've updated the post to be more specific.

Comment: so whats wrong with line.split(":") and then for each piece in the array you trim().replaceAll(""", ""); ?? you could line.split(""\\s+:\\s+"") but it wouldn't fully clean up the pieces for the first and last item in the array returned

Comment: Nothing wrong with that or the way I did it with replace, and split on the colon.  I wanted to do it one regular expression so that it is one operation as opposed to two if possible.

Comment: Think this way...you need to keep the delimiter (colon in this case) be4 splitting, so two steps are required: remove quotes & spaces & commas, then split. So two operations are the minimum. You can do them in one line ... `ary = re.sub(r"[\s\",]+", "", line).split(":")`

Comment: Or if you know for sure the words won't have special characters, you can do this with one func call , `ary = re.findall(r"\w+", line)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
usrArray = line.split("(\" : \")|(\",?)");
```

This looks first for `" : "`. If it doesnt find that it will look for the edge cases, `"` and `",`. If you need it to also search for newlines, use this regex.

```
usrArray = line.split("(\" : \")|(\",?\n?)");
```

Comment: That's really close!  I'm still getting an empty string as the first element in the returned array, but I can work around that.